# Compute to prove that $\|A\|^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ given $\rho(A)<1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

By Schur decomposion we have $\|A\|^n=\|Q^*T^nQ\|\leq \|T^n\|.$ Where $T$ is upper triangular matrix with entries on diagonal equal to eigenvalues of $A$. And I know the diagonal entires of $T^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. But how to prove $\|T^n\|\to 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same proof at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius). This can be applied both to $A$ or $T$ because they have the same spectrum and 
$\rho(A) = \rho(T) < 1$.

Note this answer doesn't use the Schur decomposition, I don't known if it is ok for you.

Comment: why the max singular value is zero given all eigenvalues are zero?

Comment: @Gatsby Sorry my error, It is not true for example matrix [ (0, 1) ; (0, 0)] has $\sigma_{max} = 1$

Comment: @Gatsby I edit the answer